# Back to cart button on checkout page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout, cart

Is there any solution to display a **"back to shopping cart"** button on the WooCommerce checkout page?

Actually there is only a complete order button, but we need a back button, if a user want to correct his order.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes it's possible to display a custom notice with a "Back to Cart" button on checkout page. Here is that custom hooked function in **`woocommerce_before_checkout_form`** action hook:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_checkout_form', 'return_to_cart_notice_button' );
function return_to_cart_notice_button(){

    // HERE Type your displayed message and text button
    $message = __('Go back to the Cart page', 'woocommerce');
    $button_text = __('Back to Cart', 'woocommerce');

    $cart_link = WC()->cart->get_cart_url();

    wc_add_notice( '<a href="' . $cart_link . '" class="button wc-forward">' . $button_text . '</a>' . $message, 'notice' );
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.

The code is tested and works.

Comment: is there a solution to get the button at the bottom of the page? maybe next to the „order now“-button?

Comment: @user6573193 Sorry but this is another question… and to have this button near the "order now" is something that is going to be very confusing. In general In all good web shops, there is a **mini cart,** button on a top bar, that allows to go back to cart …

Comment: @LoisTheAtztec: Currently the WooCommerce Mini Cart Gutenberg block hides itself on the checkout page.