# WooCommerce and hooks in thank you page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout, hook-woocommerce

I have set some php code in my website in order to limit minimum order amount, and thus, I've also added a "Back to Cart" button to be displayed in the "Checkout" page to improve user experience (based on this example: [Back to cart button on checkout page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42491380/back-to-cart-button-on-checkout-page)). The thing is, when the order is valid (matches the minimum order quantity set) when customer is redirected to the "Thank You" page, the "Back to Cart" button keeps showing up, and in this page it makes no sense, as the image shows: 
[thank you message with get back to cart button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8zBjw.png)

Is there any way to prevent it from showing up in thank you page, and keep its behaviour in checkout page?

So far, the PHP code added to functions file in my child theme is:

```
// back to cart button
add_action ( 'woocommerce_checkout_process', 'return_to_cart_notice_button', 20 );
function return_to_cart_notice_button(){

    //Set the messages for notice and button
    $message = __( 'Do you want to go back to shopping cart?', 'woocommerce' );
    $button_text = __( 'Go to shopping cart', 'woocommerce' );

    $cart_link = WC()->cart->get_cart_url();

    wc_add_notice( '<a href="' . $cart_link . '" class="button wc-forward">' . $button_text . '</a>' . $message, 'notice' );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this 2 conditionals woocommerce tags together **to target only checkout page**, but not order received (thankyou) page:

```
if( is_checkout() && ! is_wc_endpoint_url( 'order-received' ) ){ }
```

So in your code:

```
// back to cart button
add_action ( 'woocommerce_checkout_process', 'return_to_cart_notice_button', 20 );
function return_to_cart_notice_button(){

    if( is_checkout() && ! is_wc_endpoint_url( 'order-received' ) ){

        //Set the messages for notice and button
        $message = __( 'Do you want to go back to shopping cart?', 'woocommerce' );
        $button_text = __( 'Go to shopping cart', 'woocommerce' );

        $cart_link = WC()->cart->get_cart_url();

        wc_add_notice( '<a href="' . $cart_link . '" class="button wc-forward">' . $button_text . '</a>' . $message, 'notice' );
    }
}
```